# Making a product filter with multiple criteria in CSS exclusively

Tags: css, user-interface

Ive recently been making a website and im having trouble making a filter work for more than 1 criteria (for example both the color and size of a stone) at the same time.
im currently using CSS to hide the specific products that dont have the criteria when a checkbox is checked using

```
input[id="example"]:checked
```

and then using display:none
I have also tried making it display the product instead and hiding the others by default but that hasnt worked either, are there any solutions for this? (i know using javascript is an easier option but im not permitted to use it for this project)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider adding some HTML and more of your CSS logic so that I/we can provide better help.

This is how I would do it, considering your restriction of using only CSS:

```css
/* hide all items by default */
.items > * { display: none; }

/*
the toggles display all associated items.
each item needs to match at least one criteria to be shown 
*/
.filter#criteria-1:checked ~ .items .criteria-1 { display: block; }
.filter#criteria-2:checked ~ .items .criteria-2 { display: block; }
.filter#criteria-3:checked ~ .items .criteria-3 { display: block; }
```

```html
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="criteria-1" checked>
<label for="criteria-1">Criteria 1</label>
<br>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="criteria-2" checked>
<label for="criteria-2">Criteria 2</label>
<br>
<input class="filter" type="checkbox" id="criteria-3" checked>
<label for="criteria-3">Criteria 3</label>
<br>

<ul class="items">
  <li class="criteria-1 criteria-2">Item 1</li>
  <li class="criteria-1">Item 2</li>
  <li class="criteria-3">Item 3</li>
  <li class="criteria-2">Item 4</li>
  <li class="criteria-1 criteria-3">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-agnesi-4pe9y7

Comment: Note that the `<br>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specificaiton.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I removed them :)